# Merging Arrays containing hashes inside - Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, multidimensional-array, hash

hey guys if i have an array containing hashes like so:

```
random_arary = [
  {number: 123, x: 2},
  {number: 123, y: 7},
  {number: 123, z: 2},
  {number: 456, a: 3},
  {number: 456, b: 4},
  {number: 456, c: 0}
]
```

and i want to merge all the hashes into only two hashes like so:

```
random_array= 
        [
          {time: 123, x: 2, y: 7, z: 2},
          {time: 456, a: 3, b: 4, c: 0},
        ]
```

what would be a good way to approach this?

EDIT: to make my question more clear, i want to group all the hashes with the k.v pair 'number:123' together, and all the hashes with the k.v pair 'number:456' together.

In this way all hashes that start with the key value pair 'number:123' get merged into one hash, and all the hashes with the key value pair 'number:456' get merged into one hash.

Comment: Will there always be 6 hashes? Do you always want to split them in half? Does it matter which goes into which final hash? Will there always be 4 things in the hash and will the first one always be "time" with 3 letter keys after it?

Comment: What is the criteria for creating the two hashes?

Comment: Yeah, what @Beartech said. :)

Answer (score 4):

```
random_array.group_by {|x|x[:number]}.values.map {|x|x.reduce(:merge)}
# => [
#   {:number=>123, :x=>2, :y=>7, :z=>2},
#   {:number=>456, :a=>3, :b=>4, :c=>0}
# ]
```

Or, including the substitution of the `:number` key for `:time`:

```
def transform(arr)
  groups = arr.group_by {|x|x[:number]}.values.map {|x|x.reduce(:merge)}
  groups.each { |x| x[:time] = x[:number]; x.delete(:number) }
end
```

Comment: Nice - although you haven't catered for the seemingly arbitrary renaming of `:number` to `:time` (!)

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use the form of [Hash#update](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-update) (aka `merge!`) that uses a block to determine the values of keys that are present in both hashes being merged:

```
random_array.each_with_object({}) do |g,h|
  h.update(g[:number]=>g.reject { |k,_| k==:number }) { |_,o,n| o.update(n) }
end.map { |nbr,h| h.merge(:time=>nbr) }
  #=> [{:x=>2, :y=>7, :z=>2, :time=>123}, {:a=>3, :b=>4, :c=>0, :time=>456}]
```